# Wine on 64 bit Ubuntu : Must Build Biarch Wine On Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, 64-bit, 32-bit, lxc

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu says

> Ubuntu's implementation of Multiarch is still incomplete, so for now you can't simply install 32-bit and 64-bit libraries alongside each other. If you're on a 64-bit system, you'll have to create an isolated environment for installing and building with 32-bit dependencies. See Building Biarch Wine On Ubuntu for detailed instructions for Ubuntu using LXC, and Building Wine for general information.

I'm confused.

So what does it mean? Must I build Wine from scratch?
I'm running Ubuntu 17 64 bit.

Comment: I think that may refer to much older versions of Ubuntu (14.04 and 15.x) perhaps? The "Biarch" wiki page there was last edited in January 2016. There are also wine-i386 and wine-amd64 packages in the 16.04 archive.

Comment: "Must I build Wine from scratch?"  No you are meant to follow that webpage you link to if you want to use BOTH 32 and 64-bit software. Stick to 64-bit and you are fine with normal Ubuntu software center version of wine (and do install play on linux too)